# F# Type casting an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, casting, f#

I have 2 arrays. Array 1 is a string array that contains the names of types.

So the contents of Array 1 looks like this:

```
["nvarchar";"nvarchar";"date";"nvarchar"] //these are all strings
```

Array 2 is another array of strings and the contents look like this:

```
["Jackson";"Sentzke";"1991-04-19T00:00:00";"Jackson Sentske"]
```

My problem is that all the values in Array 2 are strings, and I want them to be of the types in Array 1. Is there a way that I can type cast the strings in Array 2 using the strings in Array 1?

Comment: First, obviously those are SQL column types and not .NET types. Second, you cannot really have an array of different types. Third, that's what type providers are for, and SQLProvider has a nifty .Mapto method that does this. You should be storing this in an array of records, and your life would be much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @s952163 points out, it looks like you're attempting to read data from a database, in which case **there are better options available** than trying to do it yourself. Still, just to sketch out a possible solution if taking the OP at face value, here's one way to go about it.

Since the types listed aren't .NET types, perhaps it's better to define a custom type to hold such values:

```
open System

type DbType = NVarChar of string | DT of DateTime
```

You can add more cases to `DbType` if you'd like.

Using [active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns), you can write a function to convert a single candidate:

```
// string * string -> string option
let (|NVarChar|_|) = function
    | "nvarchar", (x : string) -> Some x
    | _ -> None

// string * string -> DateTime option
let (|DT|_|) (typeHint, value) =
    match (typeHint, DateTime.TryParse value) with
    | "date", (true, dt) -> Some dt
    | _ -> None

// string * string -> DbType option    
let convertPair = function
    | NVarChar x -> Some (NVarChar x)
    | DT x -> Some (DT x)
    | _ -> None
```

The use of active patterns isn't strictly necessary, but I thought it enabled me to decompose the problem in a good way.

Now you can declare a list of types and one of values, zip them together to get a list of interpreted values:

```
> let types = ["nvarchar"; "nvarchar"; "date"; "nvarchar"];;    
val types : string list = ["nvarchar"; "nvarchar"; "date"; "nvarchar"]

> let values = ["Jackson"; "Sentzke"; "1991-04-19T00:00:00"; "Jackson Sentske"];;    
val values : string list =
  ["Jackson"; "Sentzke"; "1991-04-19T00:00:00"; "Jackson Sentske"]

> let converted = List.zip types values |> List.choose convertPair;;    
val converted : DbType list =
  [NVarChar "Jackson"; NVarChar "Sentzke"; DT 19.04.1991 00:00:00;
   NVarChar "Jackson Sentske"]
```

Note that both `types` and `values` have the type `string list`. In the OP, they were `(string * string * string * string) list`, which I assume was a mistake.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake. Thank you for the correction. also thank you for the comment. It'll help someone. I thought it'd help me but I then realized I was asking the wrong the questions.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you have a few issues here.

**Commas create Tuples**
your code

```
["nvarchar","nvarchar","date","nvarchar"]
```

is not a `string list` but `(string * string * string * string) list`

If you want to create a `string list` you would have to use a semicolon `;`.

Now if you know that your code has always the same exact number of tuple elements with the exact types you want than you could do it like this

```
type RowItems = string * string * DateTime * string
type Rows = RowItem list
```

Now if your problem includes rows of different sizes and you want convert from or to SQL data types than maybe an approach using Discriminate Unions could be helpful.

```
type SQLDataType =
   | VarChar of string
   | Date of DateTime

type Row = SQLDataType list
type Rows = RowItem list
```

The usage then would be like this

```
let row = 
    [
        VarChar "Jackson";
        VarChar "Sentzke";
        Date DateTime.parse("1991-04-19T00:00:00");
        VarChar "Jackson Sentske"
    ]
```

finally you should write then some conversion functions that convert that from and to your SQL data

```
let fromSQL (s:string) : SQLDataType = ...
let toSQL (s:SQLDataType) : string = ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It'll help someone. I thought it'd help me but I then realized I was asking the wrong the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a low-level solution as it's not very obvious where all this is headed, but if all that is you need is for your strings to be of the db types, then T-SQL has [Cast and Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) for you. So you can just say `CAST ("1991-04-19T00:00:00" AS date)`.